# How to redirects to the sandbox use "printf" in iOS?

Tags: ios, printf, stdout, fclose, freopen

In iOS development, I would like to test the output of the log to the local file. Use the redirection can be done to "NSLog" output to the file, but if I use the "printf" output when the use `freopen([logFilePath cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], "a+", stdout);` can not do. Is there any way to make "printf" output is also redirected to the log ?

Answer (score 0):

i had fine the answer.

you can use `dup2` instand of `freopen`,just do like this:

> //将缓冲区禁止

`setvbuf(stdout,NULL,_IONBF,0);`

> //用创建的文件描述符替换掉 标准输出和错误输出

`//ignore logFilePath(just a file address).`

`int fd = open([logFilePath cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],(O_RDWR | O_CREAT), 0644);`

`dup2(fd,STDOUT_FILENO);`

`dup2(fd, STDERR_FILENO)`

then between `NSLog` and `printf` will redirected to your local.